# how to use is_invocable with variants and std::holds_alternative

Tags: c++, templates, variant

If I have a variant `Value`:

```
using Value = std::variant<bool, float>;
```

Then `std::holds_alternative()` should be callable with those types but not others:

```
Value v;
if (std::holds_alternative<bool>(v))... // compile ok
if (std::holds_alternative<float>(v))... // compile ok
if (std::holds_alternative<int>(v))... // compile error
```

Given a type T, how can I check if `std::holds_alternative<T>(const Value&)` is callable?
I want to do something like this

```
template<class T>
void check() {
    if (std::is_invocable_v<decltype(std::holds_alternative<bool>), const Value&>) {
        std::cout << "callable";
    } else {
        std::cout << "not callable";
    }
}
```

But this doesn't compile because I think it instantiates `std::holds_alternative<bool>` without considering the `Value` part.
What's the correct syntax here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, `std::holds_alternative` isn't SFINE-friendly.  All instantiations of `std::holds_alternative` are invokable, but they contain a `static_assert` that prevents the calls from compiling if its requirements aren't met.

That means there's no good way to write your `check` function in terms of `std::holds_alternative` directly.  Instead, you can implement it in terms of `std::holds_alternative`'s underlying requirement that the given type appears exactly once in the variant's type list:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t count_in_pack()
{
    std::array<bool, sizeof...(Ts)> a = { std::is_same_v<T, Ts>... };
    return std::count(a.begin(), a.end(), true);
}

template <typename... Ts>
void check(const std::variant<Ts...>&)
{
    if (count_in_pack<bool, Ts...>() == 1) {
        std::cout << "callable\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "not callable\n";
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c89cf78bb66655ce)

Or, if you want to be able to call `check` with just the type, and no actual instance of a `std::variant` then you can use a helper class with partial specialization:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t count_in_pack()
{
    std::array<bool, sizeof...(Ts)> a = { std::is_same_v<T, Ts>... };
    return std::count(a.begin(), a.end(), true);
}

template <typename T, typename V>
struct CanCallHoldsAlternative
    : std::false_type
{};

template <typename T, typename... Vs>
struct CanCallHoldsAlternative<T, std::variant<Vs...>>
    : std::conditional_t<
        count_in_pack<T, Vs...>() == 1,
        std::true_type,
        std::false_type
    >
{};

template <typename T>
void check()
{
    if (CanCallHoldsAlternative<bool, T>::value) {
        std::cout << "callable\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "not callable\n";
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e638cd5ccb509847)

Comment: Many thanks for your excellent detailed reply